# Difficult situation with german student visa

Tags: visas, germany, us-citizens, study

As the title says, I'm going to be in Germany working for a research group at a university. I will be with them for 82 days and I will then be traveling with my parents for 10 days.

My problem of course, is that I will be in the Schengen area for 92 days instead of the allowed 90. I feel that I should be able to get a student visa and would then have no problem. However the German international program coordinator seems unwilling to help me. His advice was "go to Britain for 2 days." But I really don't think I want to spend the EUR 500 to go there, especially when it's just to save this guy some paperwork. I was also weighing the merits of trying to slip through the cracks on a short overstay, but after reading some horror stories I can't bring myself to test it.

I leave tomorrow and I don't even know if it's possible to get a visa anymore, so I'm freaking out that this guy's laziness might've costed me so much money. Can I get a visa and how do I get started/push this guy into helping me?

Comment: I suppose I don't want to do that because 1) flights are already booked and changing them isn't cheap. And 2) if I'm correct that it shouldn't be a problem for me to get a student visa, it's really lame to have to do that after my parents spending all that money to get over there.

Comment: @Chessnerd321 What is your nationality? What are your flight plans? If you leave tomorrow, are you expecting to apply for the visa while working in Germany? Shouldn’t you be ‘freaking out’ about the possibility of breaching immigration rules?

Comment: The UK isn't the only option.  You could also go to Croatia, Romania, Bulgaria, Serbia, Ukraine, others.

Comment: @Traveller in Germany permission to work is often separate from permission to enter and remain, so people working for a short time are often on a type C short-stay visa or indeed an Annex II visa-free stay.

Comment: @HankyPanky that's how it works for.citizens of several countries.  They enter without a visa and then apply at the Ausländerbehörde for a residence permit.

Comment: @phoog thank you for the clarification. Technically I am a student, since I'm working as an unpaid intern for university credit. That's why I think it should be no problem to get a visa. The program coordinator had assumed the standard 90 day tourist visa granted upon arrival to US citizens would be good enough, but it is not. Any advice?

Comment: There is no "standard 90 day tourist visa granted upon arrival to US citizens."  Rather, US citizens (among others) can stay for up to 90 days for any purpose without a visa, but the activities allowed are subject to national law.  Why do you think German law doesn't allow you to stay for 82 days as an unpaid research intern receiving academic credit?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I am worried because my complete stay will sum up to 92 days, 82 of which are with the school (i.e. I am covered for health and liability insurance etc.) and 10 of which are not. So I'm afraid of being popped with a huge fine for what would appear to be a 2 day overstay.

Comment: It will be a 2-day overstay, but I doubt you're going to get much help from the school since the program is only 82 days.  Really your best bet is to go away for a couple of days.  Do note that you must count both your day of entry and your day of exit, so if the 92-day count is correct, you need to spend 2 full days outside the area (for example, leave on Friday and return on Monday, or two trips where you leave on Friday and return on Sunday).

Comment: @Chessnerd321 If it helps, this calculator https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/content/visa-calculator_en will enable you to check the duration of your time in the Schengen area

Comment: -1 for a huge sense of entitlement. You go to the university for 82 days; it is unreasonable for you to expect them to go out of their way to allow you to stay for over 90 days.

Comment: 500 euros sounds *way* too expensive for a return flight to the UK from Germany. Have you tried a comparison site such as [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.net) or [Kayak](http://www.kayak.co.uk)? I don't know the details of your journey, but as a random example I checked a return flight from Berlin to London in mid June and prices were starting at 100 euros.

Comment: @fkraiem I don't know why it's "entitlement" to think I could get a student visa while being a student. I am literally working for this guy for free for a whole summer. It's not like I'm just expecting things for free. You just think you can throw that word at me just because I'm young, but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Stay 90 days or less by leaving early. As you point out, a bad idea from your viewpoint because the trip is already booked.
- Stay 90 days or less by leaving in between, to a country which allows easy or visa-free entry for US citizens. That costs money, and we don't know how tightly your program is scheduled. Can you take an "extended" weeked off?
- Stay more than 90 days with a German D visa. As you point out, the university isn't helping because they made the program 82 days -- presumably just to avoid such hassle.
- Break the law, risk a fine on departure, and risk problems with future visits.
  **Bad idea.**
  You are young. Do you want to check "yes" on questions if you have ever been fined for overstay, deported etc. for the rest of your life?

It seems to me that there are no painless, cost-free options for you. (Note that a D visa application will take significant effort from you even if the university would help. It is more than *just some paperwork.*)

I'm not in your position, but I'd probably go for leaving in between (two whole days). Ever been to the UK? That should be possible for less than €500 if you plan well ahead. A bus ticket should be less than €100, and there are many nice, scenic towns with cheaper stays than London. Just make sure that you cross the border before midnight on Friday and after midnight on Monday.

Comment: I would try to take a couple of weekend trips outside the Schengen zone, to create a small safety margin. That avoids the hassle of proving a failure to leave on time was unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I guess I'll just go to London.

Comment: @Chessnerd321, if you're on a typical student budget, don't go to **London**. 30 years ago I was cycling through the German countryside with an American and I pointed out a megalith grave more than 2000 years old. His jaws dropped that it was just in the landscape, no special museum or anything. Visit Stonehenge, maybe. If you like Robin Hood, visit Nottingham. If you like sailing ships, go to Portsmouth, even if HMS Victory is being renovated. Or go to Scotland, balancing a longer trip with cheaper accomodations than in London.